# help with proof of differentiability of the inner product of two functions

Tags: real-analysis

I have been given this question:

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Assume that $f$ is differentiable at $c$, that $f(c) = 0$, and that $g$ is continuous at $c$. Let $h(x) = \langle g(x), f(x)\rangle$. Prove that $h$ is differentiable at $c$ and that for any vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$,  $h'(c)v = \langle g(c), f'(c)(v)\rangle$

I'm having a bit of trouble rigorously proving this. It seems obvious that h would be differentiable at c since $h(c) = f(c)g(c) = 0*g(c)$ where g(c) is continuous and thus $h(c) = 0$, and a constant is always differentiable.

I think that is solid logic (maybe not), but showing the second half of the problem is a little bit more difficult. Is it enough to say that by that

$h'(c)v = g'(c)f(c)v + f'(c)g(c)v$

and since $f(c) = 0$ we can write

$h'(c)v = 0 + f'(c)g(c)v \rightarrow \langle g(c), f'(c)\rangle v$ and by the properties of inner product we can say $h'(c) = \langle g(c), f'(c)\rangle v$.

Is my intuition correct or am I missing something? Is my argument flawed in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is seriously flawed, yes.

The claim that $h' = g'f + f'g$ depends on both $f$ and $g$ being differentiable, but you know only that $g$ is continuous. If you looked at the PROOF of the multiplication rule, you might find that you could replace the assumption that $g$ is differentiable with some statement about continuity, combined with the fact that $f(0) = 0$, and therefore, because $f$ is differentiable, for some $M$, you have $|f(x)| < M|x|$ for $x$ near enough to $0$; this combination might be enough to show that in your case, $h'(0) = f'(0) g(0)$. 
(Indeed, I'm pretty certain that this line of argument works just fine.)

The earlier statement that "it's obvious that $h$ is differentiable" because a constant is always differentiable is also flawed: $h(c)$ is a constant for ANY function $h$ and any value $c$, so your argument would "show" that all functions are differentiable at all points, and that's just not true.